# Filtering leaflet markers in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, leaflet

I was to allow the user to show and hide markers in a Leaflet map by selecting the category from a list of checkboxes.

```
var createMarkers = function () {

    var markers = new L.LayerGroup({});

    Locations.find().forEach(function (location) {
        var lat, lng, category, popup
        lat = location.lat;
        lng = location.lng;
        category = location.category

        popup = "location.name + location.category;

        return markers.addLayer(new L.marker([lat, lng], {
          icon: icon
        }).bindPopup(popup));

        }
    })
}


Meteor.subscribe('locations', createMarkers);
```

I have a session that returns an array of categories based on the checkbox selection(s), but not sure the best way to then update the markers on the client based on this.

I've also considered using the Leaflet.GroupedLayerControl plugin but not sure if that's a better, Meteor way to go..

Comment: I've never used Leaflet, but I think you might be calling `addLayer` wrong? http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer

Comment: Thanks. Could use some refactoring tbh, but the main layer works fine for now without any filtering. I'm currently looking at ways to implement filtering UI and whether this is best done with sessions or whether there's a better way to handle this.